# How to change required attribute in @RequestParam?

Tags: java, spring

I have controller end point like this:

```
    @GetMapping
    public List<QuestionnaireModel> getQuestionnaireList (
        @PathVariable String userId,
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "userId") Long orderId
    ){
```

Now, how can I change my `required` attribute in `@RequestParam` depending on value that will be in `@PathVariable`?

For example :

```
if(userId==5){
    //My @RequestParam required must be true so I must provide `orderId`
}
```

Comment: I think you need to put custom logic for validation. Accordingly, you can throw the API validation errors to the caller.

Comment: You can't. You'll need to validate it manually.

Comment: You can use SpringBoot validation to achieve this. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bad API design.

```
/api/myUser/
/api/anotherUser?param=value
```

For myUser the param is not required, but for anotherUser it must be present.

You can try to use a filter to address this requirement but I would suggest you to perhaps consider again the design for your API.

How will you decide for which user the param is valid and for which it is not ?
That would require you to do some validation on the userId. If this is just a dev project ,it might be ok. But if this some serious application, maybe you should go back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

@RequestParam  & @PathVariable are two different annotations which have no common dependency. You would need to annotate @RequestParam to this method and apply validation then execute your code.

```
@RequestParam(value="something")
if(something!=null){
//code goes here
}
```